# What is the probability that the family will buy a dog?

Tags: probability

A family is considering buying a dog. The probability that they will buy a small dog is $0.1$, that they will buy a medium-size dog is $0.3$, that they will buy a large dog is $0.2$, and that they will buy a very large dog is $0.1$. What is the probability that the family will buy a dog?

Comment: Is it possible for the family to get more than one dog, or will they get at most one?

Answer (score 1):

If those cases (dog size being X) can be considered disjoint, remember that 
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\cup_i A_i\right)=\sum_i \mathbb{P}(A_i)$$

Answer (score 0):

If we want the probability that the family will buy *one or more* dogs, it is easier to find the probability that they will **not** buy any dog. It is the product of the probabilities that they will not buy each dog:
$$ 1 - P(One\ or\ more\ dogs) = P(No\ dogs) = \prod_{s\in Sizes}\left(1 - P(s)\right)$$
Assuming  that those events are independent.

In other case, if we want the probability that the family will buy *exactly* one dog. We should consider the sum of the probabilities that they will buy a dog of a specific size and not buy any other.

$$ \sum_{s\in Sizes} \left(P(s) \prod_{v \in Sizes\setminus\{s\}} (1-P(v)) \right)$$

Supposing again that those events are independent. That is, we consider that it is possible for the family to get more than one dog.